# Mongodb server specs

Tags: mongodb

May i ask what is the best server specs for mongodb?

With initial request of 5k - 10k read / writes.

I don't have any idea with this please help me.

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: There are some general guidelines on [Hardware Requirements](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/production-notes/#hardware-requirements-and-limitations) in the MongoDB documentation, but the details depend on many different factors such as your application use cases, size of your working set, and available RAM. One way to get started would be to estimate your requirements based on profiling in your development/QA environment; you could also use a [hosted service](http://www.10gen.com/partners/cloudservices) to get started quickly.  See also: http://serverfault.com/questions/237505.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normal configuration desktop should be able to handle this requirement.  But may not be recommended for the production deployment.

But 10Gen, the mongodb company recommends $7K - $10K range boxes for optimal performance (in their free course offered a month ago).  You can watch 9th video of playlist 7 about [MongoDB DBA Tutorials](http://muruga.yoksha.com/mongodb-dba-video-tutorials.html) or [Hardware Requirements](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19VZJ9H3LmQ&list=PL-mmKfP9K7p-EjmZg2vke86WUooEgNIDs).

Again it varies based on different facts and you can take some tips from these videos to move forward.

Comment: The $7-10k figure in the DBA tutorial is taken somewhat out of context; the discussion is around pros & cons of running many low cost servers versus running fewer more powerful servers. The appropriate sizing and configuration will vary based on your use case and there is no generic number. It's a bit like answering the question of "what car should you buy" ;-).

Comment: @Stennie is indeed right (of course). I am fairly sure my servers actually cost closer to about $14 a month rather than a $10K price tag. I get optimal performance for my data on my current setup. There is no right or wrong answer on how to setup your servers, it is all down to what you need.